# Send binary data through pipes C

Tags: c, binary, fork, pipe

I have a problem with child processes and pipes in C.

My program creates two child processes (silblings) and also two pipes. The father reads from `stdin` and sends the data through the first pipe. The first child redirects the `stdin` to the first pipe and the `stdout` to the second pipe. After that the child runs `gzip -cf` with `execlp(3)`. The second child reads from the second pipe and writes the data in the `stdout` (or in a file).

I tried it but it doesnt work with the binary data. If the first child only sends the text data through the second pipe (without using gzip) and the second child reads it, the program works fine. But if I use gzip with `execlp()` and the process writes binary data the program doesn't work, because  I don't get all data.

Here is a part of the code:

First child:

```
/* Close the pipe-ends which are not needed [...]  */
/* Redirect the stdin and stdout with dup2 [...]  */

if(execlp(EXEC,EXEC_ARG0,EXEC_ARG1,(char*) 0) == -1) /* run execlp with 'gzip -cf' */
   bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE,"Child_1:  Cannot execute "EXEC_ARG0" "EXEC_ARG1"!");
```

Second child:

```
/* Close the pipe-ends which are not needed [...] */

FILE *fd = NULL;
char str[4096];

fd = fdopen(pipefd_com2[0],"rb");
(void) fread(str,sizeof(str),1,fd); /* read from pipe */
(void) fclose(fd);

FILE *fw = NULL;

if(file_arg == NULL) /* check if there was a file as argument */
   fw = stdout;
else
   fw = fopen(file_arg,"wb");

if(fw == NULL)
   bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE,"Failed to write file!"); /* does not return */

(void) fwrite(str,strlen(str),1,fw); /* write to stdout or file */
(void) fclose(fw);
```

Comment: The intentional cast-to-void in this code to squelch unchecked return value warnings from whatever static analysis is scrutinizing your code are particularly inconvenient, since in at least one case **not** checking those values is part of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strlen` function is for C-style strings, not for binary data. Also, your parameters to `fread` are wrong. The second parameter is the size of *each object* you are reading. For arbitrary binary data, that should be `1`, since each object is a byte. That will make the return value from `fread` the number of bytes you read, which is what you'll need to pass to `fwrite` as the third parameter.

In sum:

```
size_t bytes_read;
// ...
bytes_read = fread(str,1,sizeof(str),fd); /* read from pipe */
// ...
(void) fwrite(str,1,bytes_read,fw); /* write to stdout or file */
```

You should also check the return value from `fread`.